# Starting matlab from engOpen(..), being notified of engine being closed

Tags: c++, c, matlab

If I start a matlab engine using the api function engOpen, and then set the engine's visibilty to TRUE, do I have any way of being notified if the user shuts the engine down (as they can do )?

More generally, after opening an instance and making it visible, do I have any way of knowing if the engine pointer I hold is still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, why can you use [`engGetVariable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/enggetvariable.html) which returns pointer to a newly allocated mxArray structure, or NULL if the attempt fails.  So when starting the engine, initiate also a dummy variable and then if `engGetVariable` fails it means the named dummy variable does not exist, which should imply the engine down... Of course you want to prevent from the user deleting that variable too...